# Delphi ADO with Excel 2010 or newer, problems with .RecordCount

Tags: delphi, excel, ado, delphi-xe, vba

I have a case here where I use excel files connected with ADO, it seems OK with excel 2003 files, however when I use excel 2007 or newer I get some problems receiving recordcount..

my connection string look like this for excel 2003 :

```
format('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;',[filename])
```

and the same connectionstring for excel 2007 or newer (xlsx files)

```
format('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"',[filename])
```

do I need something more here? or what am I missing to be allowed to use the recordcount, recno etc etc?

Comment: How about telling us the precise error message?

Comment: If `RecordCount` returns 0 or -1, then the behavior is not to be unexpected. If it's an error, then, like David, i'm curious to see the error.

Comment: As David and Ian said, "I get some problems" doesn't provide any information we can use to help. If you have a problem, you need to tell us what the problem is, and if you have an error you need to provide the exact error message.

Comment: yep as lan mention, i get -1 as recordcount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this article:
http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=33

Basically you need to set the `CursorType` to something other than `ctOpenForwardOnly`.

Comment: Just reinstalled Delphi XE, so will test this as soon as possible